# Ajax JSON empty passing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

To all whom it may concern (I am really just trying to reach the "please add more detail" limit)

When passing data to the server as below the body is shown as empty.

**Server**

```
// POST method route
app.post('/pass', function (req, res) {
  console.log("server received POST from homepage")
  console.log(req.body)
  res.send('POST request to the homepage')
})
```

**Client**

```
function ajaxJSONFunc(){
      var inputData = document.getElementById('input2').value

      var json = {"data":"abc"};

      $.ajax({
        url: "/pass",
        type: "POST",
        data: json
        contentType: "application/json",
        // dataType: "json", only use if you need to responce data to be JSON, if its not JSON an error will fire when uncommented. defaults to text
        success: function(data) {
         console.log("data passed back from server is:" + data)
        },
        error: function(err) {
           console.log("an error occured")
           console.log(err)
        }
      })
}
```

Works when passing like this (below), but I would prefer to send JSON data and not strings

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "/pass",
    type: "POST",
    data: inputData,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    //dataType: "json", only use if you need to responce data to be JSON, if its not JSON an error will fire when uncommented. defaults to text
    success: function(data) {
     console.log("data passed back from server is:" + data)
    },
    error: function(err) {
       console.log("an error occured")
       console.log(err)
    }
  })
```

Comment: Try to use this :`data: JSON.stringify(json)`;

Comment: `I would prefer to send JSON data and not strings` Note that JSON *is* a string

Comment: do you `require('body-parser')` in your server code?

Comment: Currently you're not trying to send JSON, you're trying to send an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `contentType: "application/json"`. That's means you have to send a `json` object.

You have to use `JSON.stringify()` method.

```
data: JSON.stringify(json)
```

**JSON.stringify function turns a Javascript object into JSON text and stores it in a string.**

Comment: I apologise profusely - I really thought jQuery did that automatically - this is the correct answer! - you may want to add that this works as long as the server includes `bodyParser = require('body-parser')` and `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: app.use(bodyParser.json()); Hnngh I was using the wrong parser i.e app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); regardless this is correct too I cut stingify away when I started getting annoyed and tried just cutting stuff out trying to use the process of elimination.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var json = "abc";
 $.ajax({
        url: "/pass",
        type: "POST",
        data: json,
        contentType: "application/json",
        // dataType: "json", only use if you need to responce data to be JSON, if its not JSON an error will fire when uncommented. defaults to text
        success: function(data) {
         console.log("data passed back from server is:" + data)
        },
        error: function(err) {
           console.log("an error occured")
           console.log(err)
        }
      });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that's not sending **json**

Comment: you are effectively doing what I showed did work >.<